# If a linear eq. System has only a single solution, the matrix has always an inverse?

Tags: inverse, matrix-calculus

If i have a 3x3 matrix of a linear eq. System and i archieve an upper triangular matrix (means unique solution) does this form always have inverse matrix?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, if the system has a unique solution, the matrix must be invertible.

Comment: "... i archieve an upper triangular matrix (means unique solution)...". It is non-sense. Rewrite your post.

Comment: if your system of equation has only one solution, then yes, the corresponding matrix is invertible. However, not all upper-triangular matrices are invertible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a linear eq system has only a single solution (Cramer's system) iff the matrix associated to the system is squar (nombers variable = nombers equation) and the matrice is inversible (determinant not 0).

Comment: "...iff the matrix associated to the system is squar (nombers variable = nombers equation) and ..."  .That is false. Consider the system $x=1,y=2,x+y=3$.